# How to write css to change shipping info label on checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: css, checkout

how to write css for changing shipping info on check out page in woocommerce?
I solve that in cart page but not in check out page.

Thank you
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p544u.png

Comment: plz explain more

Comment: I want to change background color and letters on that part. It is check out page, shipping label.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain a little more. The selected element in the screenshot has a `woocommerce-info` class, add `style=""` to directly customize the background (e.g.) if that is what you want to do

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

In this part, we’ll explain how to use some codes to customize the WooCommerce checkout page. So, towards the end, you’ll be able to:

Customize the WooCommerce checkout page with custom fields
Create and save custom fields in the database
Use shortcodes in mandatory field optional
Fill in the details on the WooCommerce checkout page
Customize the Checkout page with the fee option
Use shortcodes in the WooCommerce checkout page
Style the checkout page with custom CSS

Comment: In which part? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).